# Need help accessing current arrival rate value in Anylogic scheduling

Tags: scheduling, anylogic

I relatively started new with Anylogic and I have not so much experience with programing (and with Java at all).
I build an arrival schedule (schedule) with the explicit values for each day.
Now I want to make my process depending from the arrival rate. I created a variable where i used the function "schedule.getValue()" but it is only getting the first arrival rate. After the arrival rate changes it is still the first value.

Does someone know how to call the actual Value?

Thanks in forward!

schedule.getValue()

Comment: The method always returns the "current" value. If the model time is outside of all defined entries, it returns the schedule's default value. Either you did not test it thoroughly or you found a bug (very unlikely). Share more details of the setup or test it again :)

Comment: Hi Benjamin, thank you very much! When I put the Code directly in SelectOutput, then it is working. Maybe it is only for variables. (That maybe means that variables cant change)

Comment: Nope, there is another reason, search SOF for "AnyLogic on at exit" to understand what is happening